# CSS Is Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, django, webpack

So my project is running on a django backend with React for the frontend. The issue I am having is that my react components are rendering, but they are not structured correctly (margins messed up, no borders, components overlapping) even though my CSS is correct. I think the cause is in the base.html in the django portion of the project, as webpack is bundling through that. I tried adding link references to no avail.

Note* I am importing Dashboard as a const into the UserApp class which, while I don't think is the cause of the issue, could be the culprit, not sure.

How its supposed to look: https://postimg.cc/TKKtL00S

How it looks: https://postimg.cc/qhwsZ6Qy

Base.html:

```
    {% block css %}
    {% compress css %}
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/LineIcons.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialdesignicons.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fullcalendar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fullcalendar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../rsm-app-react/Dashboard.css"> -->
    {% endcompress %}
    {% compress css %}
    <!-- <link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    {% endcompress %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block css_extra %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css">

    {% endblock %}
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="app">
    </div>

    {% block javascript %}
      <!-- Latest JQuery -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- place project specific Javascript in this file -->
      {% compress js %}
      <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/project.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/dynamic-pie-chart.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/fullcalendar.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/jvectormap.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/world-merc.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/polyfill.js' %}"></script>

      {% endcompress %}
    {% endblock javascript %}
    {% block javascript_extra %}
      {% comment %} {% render_bundle 'vendor' %}
      {% render_bundle 'main' %} {% endcomment %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Dashboard.js:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { setCurrentColor, setCurrentMode, currentMode, activeMenu, currentColor, themeSettings, setThemeSettings } = useStateContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentThemeColor = localStorage.getItem('colorMode');
    const currentThemeMode = localStorage.getItem('themeMode');
    if (currentThemeColor && currentThemeMode) {
      setCurrentColor(currentThemeColor);
      setCurrentMode(currentThemeMode);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={currentMode === 'Dark' ? 'dark' : ''}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="flex relative dark:bg-main-dark-bg">
          <div className="fixed right-4 bottom-4" style={{ zIndex: '1000' }}>
            <TooltipComponent
              content="Settings"
              position="Top"
            >
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => setThemeSettings(true)}
                style={{ background: currentColor, borderRadius: '50%' }}
                className="text-3xl text-white p-3 hover:drop-shadow-xl hover:bg-light-gray"
              >
                <FiSettings />
              </button>

            </TooltipComponent>
          </div>
          {activeMenu ? (
            <div className="w-72 fixed sidebar dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg bg-white ">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="w-0 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
          )}
          <div
            className={
              activeMenu
                ? 'dark:bg-main-dark-bg  bg-main-bg min-h-screen md:ml-72 w-full  '
                : 'bg-main-bg dark:bg-main-dark-bg  w-full min-h-screen flex-2 '
            }
          >
            <div className="fixed md:static bg-main-bg dark:bg-main-dark-bg navbar w-full ">
              <Navbar />
            </div>
            <div>
              {themeSettings && (<ThemeSettings />)}

              <Routes>
                {/* dashboard  */}
                <Route path="/" element={(<Ecommerce />)} />
                <Route path="/ecommerce" element={(<Ecommerce />)} />

                {/* pages  */}
                <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />
                <Route path="/employees" element={<Employees />} />
                <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />

                {/* apps  */}
                <Route path="/kanban" element={<Kanban />} />
                <Route path="/editor" element={<Editor />} />
                <Route path="/calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
                <Route path="/color-picker" element={<ColorPicker />} />

                {/* charts  */}
                <Route path="/line" element={<Line />} />
                <Route path="/area" element={<Area />} />
                <Route path="/bar" element={<Bar />} />
                <Route path="/pie" element={<Pie />} />
                <Route path="/financial" element={<Financial />} />
                <Route path="/color-mapping" element={<ColorMapping />} />
                <Route path="/pyramid" element={<Pyramid />} />
                <Route path="/stacked" element={<Stacked />} />

              </Routes>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard:
```

UserApp.js:

```
class UserApp extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(fetchUser())
  }

  render() {
    const {user}  = this.props
    return (
      <>
        <Dashboard/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    saveUser: (user) => dispatch(saveUser(user)),
    changeUserName: (name) => dispatch(changeUserName(name)),
    dispatch: dispatch
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserApp)
```

Comment: EDIT: Issue is fixed, needed reference to tailwind in base html